# How to use default manager in django migrations with inherited models?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-managers

I have a model `Baz` that's inheriting from an abstract model `Bar` which is inheriting as well from an other abstract model `Foo`.

```py
from django.db import models


class BarManager(models.Manager):
    pass


class Foo(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Bar(Foo):
    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bar_objects = BarManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Baz(Bar):
    attr3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

when running a data migration I want to be able to use the default manager `Baz.objects`:

```py
# Generated by Django 3.0.7 on 2020-06-23 15:57

from django.db import migrations


def update_forward(apps, schema_editor):
    Baz = apps.get_model('migration_manager', 'Baz')
    Baz.objects.filter(attr1='bar').update(attr1='baz')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('migration_manager', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_forward),
    ]
```

but it's not available as I'm getting:

```
  File "/home/user/code/django_issues/migration_manager/migrations/0002_update_content.py", line 8, in update_forward
    Baz.objects.filter(attr1='bar').update(attr1='baz')
AttributeError: type object 'Baz' has no attribute 'objects'
```

This is the initial migration that gets created automatically

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.7 on 2020-06-23 16:13

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.manager


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Baz',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('attr1', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('attr2', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('attr3', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('bar_objects', django.db.models.manager.Manager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

in there there is the `managers` section which is explicitly making available only the custom model of the parent.

Does anyone have an idea if it's me doing something wrong or it's an issue with django?

I'm on:

- ubuntu 19.10
- python 3.8.2
- django 3.0.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Model._default_manager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._default_manager) as

```
Baz._default_manager
```

Full example:

```py
def update_forward(apps, schema_editor):
    Baz = apps.get_model('migration_manager', 'Baz')
    Baz._default_manager.filter(attr1='bar').update(attr1='baz')
```